# Is there a way to convert a variable that can be either a datetime or a date to a date?

Tags: python

I have a function that can accept a date or a datetime as one of its arguments.  If the value is a datetime, I would like to convert it to its `date` components.  What is the pythonic way of doing that?

Comment: `if isinstance(param_date, datetime.datetime): param_date = paramdate.date()`

Comment: using `.date()` method...?

Comment: @Dadep, the `.date()` method doesn't exist for the date object.  I already tried it.

Comment: I think it's worth asking: why bother with the conversion?  Since `datetime` is a subclass of `date` you should be able to use a datetime as a date without making any changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `datetime` objects **are** `date` objects, you should be able to call any `date` functions on `datetime` and have it work.

But if you must:

```
if isinstance(param_date, datetime.datetime): 
    param_date = param_date.date()
```

will normallize any `datetime` and `date` objects to `date` objects... now you only have to deal with them, as `date` objects are not `datetime` objects:

```
>>> isinstance(datetime.date.today(), datetime.datetime)
False
```

**NOTE**: the reverse is not applicable:

```
>>> isinstance(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.date)
True
```

as `datetime` inherits from `date`.

Answer (score 0):

You could first check if it is of type `datetime.datetime` and then go on to convert it to its `date` component using [`datetime.datetime.date()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date).

An example of this in code would be as follows.

Importing the `datetime` module, and setting a variable `d` to be the current `datetime`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 7, 22, 10, 51, 89213)
```

Then checking if `d` is a `datetime` object, and if it is set it to be its `date` counterpart.

```
>>> if type(d) is datetime.datetime:
>>>     d = d.date()
>>> d
datetime.date(2017, 4, 7)
```